# Botão em Html ao passar rato

Tags: html

estou com um problema ao fazer um botão com saliencia ao passar o rato.

```
<td id="Consulta" class="Title"  > <a id="link_abre" href="consultas.html">
<img id="Consulta" src="images/Consulta.PNG" width="65px" height="65px"  
onclick="window.open(filtro.php)"  style="vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 8px;">

Consultas&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero alterar o primeiro para um semelhante com o segundo botão. 
Ao passar o rato ficar dessa forma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seletor CSS `:Hover` me parece a melhor opção.

### Exemplo: `:Hover` com transição

HTML:

```
<img class='dizzyimg' src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130222162701/coasterpedia/images/thumb/5/58/Magnifying_glass.png/240px-Magnifying_glass.png">
```

CSS:

```
 .dizzyimg {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
    border: 1px solid White;
}

 .dizzyimg:hover {
 -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(180deg);
    border: 1px outset #e0e0e0;
}
```

[Clique aqui para ver o JSFiffle deste exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/f8GvN/7/).

Comment: So uma duvida. Quando mostra as saliencias eles não aparecem no centro. Há forma de corrigir isso? http://jsfiddle.net/kxtC7/